# Retrieving input from dynamically created forms in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

I am new to javascript and html and I am writing a program that displays a dropdown list and depending on what option is selected, I then display two radio buttons and a textfield. I am having trouble getting access to the values of these inputs (both for the radio buttons and for the text box).

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var texts = document.getElementById("texts");

        select.onchange = function()
        {
            var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

            texts.innerHTML = "";
            if (val == "employees")
            {
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_employees"  value="select_money" /> ></div>';
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_employees"  value="select_money1" /> <</div>';
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="input_employees"  value="select_employees" /></div>';
                //var realValue = document.getElementByName('input_employees')[0].value;
                //texts.innerHTML += '<div>realValue</div>';


            }

            if (val == "total_money")
            {
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_money"  value="select_money" /> ></div>';
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_money"  value="select_money1" /> <</div>';

                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="input_money"' + '" value="select_money" /></div>';
            }

            if (val == "hits")
            {
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_hits"  value="select_money" /> ></div>';
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_hits"  value="select_money1" /> <</div>';

                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="input_hits"' + '" value="select_hits" /></div>';
            }

            if (val == "time_founded")
            {
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_time"  value="select_money" /> before date </div>';
                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="radio" name="condition_time"  value="select_money1" /> after date</div>';

                texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="input_time"' + '" value="select_date" /></div>';
            }

        }
    }
    var print = function()
    {
        var category = document.droplist.select.value;
        document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = category


    }

</script>

<body>      
    <form name="droplist" action="html_form_action.asp" method = "get">
    <select id="select" size="1">
        <option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
        <option value="employees">Number of Employees</option>
        <option value="hits">Hits on TechCrunch</option>
        <option value="time_founded">Time Founded</option>
        <option value="total_money">Total Money</option>
        </select>

        <hr/>

        <div id="texts"></div>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="print()"/>
    </form> 
        <div id="category"></div>

</body>
```

I tried to do this by using "//var realValue = document.getElementByName('input_employees')[0].value;" but this is clearly not working. I would also like to know how to then pass on this information as a paramater for a function in my python app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I suggest the following:

1. Don't re-write the `<div>`s in your javascript. You can write to the `<div>`'s innerHTML.
2. Instead of constantly writing these values, why not disable/enable as necessary?

I unfortunately cannot comment on the question, so I had to post here. Sorry about that.

Comment: I noticed a small error in my answer previously. I had advised not to used `<divs>` when I should have said not to "re-write `<div>`s" each time. I think my answer is more clear now.

Comment: If i take out the <div> tags, I receive an error. Could you give an example on how to 'disable/enable' values? Im new to this language and pretty lost right about now

Comment: The short answer to what I meant is something along the lines of this<br/>
http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/
<br/>
However, you can change your code such that you only show/hide `<div>`s without the need of buttons, links, etc.
<br/><br/>
Try switching all the inputs you want to hide by adding the `style` attribute as follows: `style="display:none;"`